# Include Header file from another package - Indigo

Tags: ros, catkin, include, find-package, library

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi folks,

I have a file called (every name here is FAKE) file.h from the package named "my_package."

Now, main.cpp located inside package named "the_package" needs to include the library in this manner:

```
#include <file.h>
```

but "the_package" cannot find file.h
How do I make catkin allow "the_package" to find file.h **without** having to do something like:

```
#include "../../../my_package/file.h"
```

I am assuming I have to do it in my CMakeList.txt, but using find_package() nor find_package(catkin Required ...) are doing it.

Every package is located inside my "catkin_ws" workspace.

What is the proper way?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/201977/include-header-file-from-another-package---indigo/) by [Pototo](https://answers.ros.org/users/11046/pototo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 803 on 2015-01-28

Post score: 9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You must install the header `file.h` from the package called `my_package`. You can do that by using this CMake snippet in the `CMakeLists.txt` file in the `my_package` package:

```
## Install project namespaced headers
install(DIRECTORY include/${PROJECT_NAME}/
  DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_INCLUDE_DESTINATION}
  FILES_MATCHING PATTERN "*.h"
  PATTERN ".svn" EXCLUDE)
```

Note that this assumes your headers, in this case `file.h`, are in your package under the `include/<project name>` folder, which for `my_package` would be `include/my_package/file.h`. This is a good practice, since all header files for all packages can be installed to the same place and you wouldn't want your `file.h` and another package's to collide. This also means that the `main.cpp` in `the_package` should do `#include <my_package/file.h>` instead of what you listed above.

Then the `the_package` package must:

- have a `build_depend` on `my_package` in its `package.xml`
- have called `find_package(my_package REQUIRED)` in its `CMakeLists.txt`
- add `my_package`'s exported include directories by doing `include_directories(${my_package_INCLUDE_DIRS})`

The `include_directories(...)` CMake call needs to come after the `find_package(...)` call.

Each of those points above ensures that:

- `my_package` is built before `the_package`
- `my_package` exists and can be found through CMake
- the location of the headers exported by `my_package` is passed to the compiler for the libraries and executables in `the_package`

Note that you can also do `find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS my_package ...)` instead of `find_package(my_package REQUIRED)`, where the `...` maybe other packages that `the_package` depends on.
Doing this would allow you to use the `catkin_` prefixed CMake variables, so you would do `include_directories(${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS})` rather than `include_directories(${my_package_INCLUDE_DIRS})`.

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2015-01-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 31

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Pototo](https://answers.ros.org/users/11046/pototo/) on 2015-01-28**:
The installation process needs to be done for the all the related files of which the_package depends on. That includes doing it for the packages that my_package depends on as well. Super recursive process haha.

Thanks

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2015-01-28**:
Each one has to follow the procedure correctly, but it's the same for them all, except that `<build_export_depends>` may be required when there are transitive dependencies.

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2015-01-29**:
If you are chaining these libraries across packages then, as @joq said, you'll need to make sure you declare the `build_export_depends` so that transitive dependencies are respected. I didn't mention transitive dependencies because you didn't say you were doing that in your original question.

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2015-01-29**:
This documentation should help: http://docs.ros.org/indigo/api/catkin/html/howto/format2/building_libraries.html

**Comment by [Raul Gui](https://answers.ros.org/users/14636/raul-gui/) on 2015-06-19**:
I tried this and doesn't work, because in CMakeLists.txt of my_package is missing:

```
catkin_package(
  INCLUDE_DIRS include
)
```

with yours steps and adding this resolve the problem.

**Comment by [Raul Gui](https://answers.ros.org/users/14636/raul-gui/) on 2015-06-19**:
but if you put:
catkin_package(
INCLUDE_DIRS include
LIBRARIES create_lib
CATKIN_DEPENDS roscpp rospy std_msgs
DEPENDS system_lib
)
you get a CMake Error:
Project 'the_package' tried to find library 'my_package'.  The library is neither a target nor

**Comment by [yash_5](https://answers.ros.org/users/28928/yash_5/) on 2018-11-07**:
After following the above steps, I get the following error.

```
CMake Error at /opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/custom_install.cmake:13 (_install):  install DIRECTORY given no DESTINATION!  Call Stack (most recent call first): CMakeLists.txt:19 (install)
```

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2018-11-07**:
@yash_5 you should probably create a new question and reference this. This is a fairly old question and the you'll probably get a better response by making a new one.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

First, "my_package" should export the library and its header file like this:

- [Building and installing C++ libraries and headers](http://docs.ros.org/indigo/api/catkin/html/howto/format2/building_libraries.html). If there is only the header, ignore the parts about the libraries.

The header should be in `include/my_package/file.h`, and will be referenced like this:

```
#include <my_package/file.h>
```

Any packages including that header needs to follow the relevant parts of these directions:

- [C++ catkin library dependencies](http://docs.ros.org/indigo/api/catkin/html/howto/format2/catkin_library_dependencies.html)

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2015-01-28

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 15

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2015-01-28**:
I like this answer better, it links to the docs, which is what I should have done.

**Comment by [Pototo](https://answers.ros.org/users/11046/pototo/) on 2015-01-28**:
Yeah, I was looking for that documentation for a few weeks now. Google would always point me to the very general catkin link on the ros.org website.

Thanks for pointing out the direct documentation linked. I found my answer